# m2e default lifecycle when adding webapp to tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2eclipse

I'm using m2eclipse for a while, and I suddenly ask myself this very basic question:

Which maven phases are part of the lifecycle when I drag and drop a webapp into my tomcat server?

I assume it must be something like "clean package" PLUS a deployment of the package into the tomcat webapp directory.
But I can't find an article defining it precisely.
Also, is this default behaviour overridable?

Am I totaly wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're right - you will typicaly go through (regardless of whether you use the `m2eclipse` or the commandline version)

- the `clean` lifeycle (refer to the standard phases in this lifecycle [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference))
- the `default` lifeycle, particularly the phases from `validate` thru `package` (again, refer to the standard phases in this lifecycle [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference))

by running

```
mvn clean package
```

Quoting the [doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) further (*emphasis* mine),

> Some phases have goals bound to them by default. And for the default
>   lifecycle, these bindings depend on the packaging value (*which in your
>   case should be `war`*).

So the `maven-war-plugin` handles the packaging for you to deploy (not to be confused with the `Maven` `deploy`) it to a tomcat instance in your case.

Although you will usually want to `install` it to your local `m2` repository and `deploy` it to a remote `m2` repository for the artifact (`*.war`) to be available in environments other than your local. For that, you will want to go further into the `default` lifecycle depending on your need.

---

Also, the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` can help you deploy the artifact on any tomcat server, you will just need to attach the right goal to the appropriate phase. Read more about the use of the plugin [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html).