# Maven: exclude resource from war

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-war-plugin

I am currently trying to exclude some resource from my built war.
I have read the documentation and the forums, and found a lot of informations.

Unfortunately nothing worked in my case...

I have an Eclipse Maven project, and if I'm right, `maven-war-plugin` is the default "war builder", so I have to override it in my pom.xml in order to exclude the resource from the buildt war.

I tried `warSourceExcludes`, `packagingExcludes` and `webResources/excludes` :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.war.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <warSourceExcludes>src/main/webapp/frontEndWorkspace</warSourceExcludes>
        <packagingExcludes>src/main/webapp/frontEndWorkspace
        </packagingExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/frontEndWorkspace</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Despite this configuration, I still have the `frontEndWorkspace` directory pushed in my Tomcat...

I wonder if it comes from the fact that I use it in my Eclipse environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to run on plain command line without any IDE...

Comment: No It is true that I use my IDE. Why? Is there some problem to use maven into eclipse? It is not the same behaviour for the default build?

Answer (score 4):

The parameters that you can use are `packagingExcludes` which is more generic (applies on the complete war structure) or `warSourceExcludes` if the files you want to exclude are specifically in the folder defined by the parameter `warSourceDirectory` (default being `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`) [(see here)](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html). It works easily when you know that it starts considering the folder structure of the war.

Example :

*This will exclude all the files finishing by `*.jsp` contained in the folder `WEB-INF` of the folder defined by the parameter `warSourceDirectory` (default being `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`) :*

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/**/*.jsp</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*This will exclude all the files contained in all the folders `pouet` contained in the war (but not the folder structure) :*

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>**/pouet/**/*.*</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem of your configuration `<warSourceExcludes>src/main/webapp/frontEndWorkspace</warSourceExcludes>` is that you start from the source folder which is wrong. You just have to remove `src/main/webapp` and add `/**` after `frontEndWorkspace` to have `<warSourceExcludes>/frontEndWorkspace/**</warSourceExcludes>` working (or `<warSourceExcludes>frontEndWorkspace/**</warSourceExcludes>`).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but it is still not working, as said above I am using eclipse IDE, so I wonder if it is not the cause of my problem...

Comment: Which goals do you run ? 'mvn clean package' ?

Comment: Which version of the plugin and maven itself ? I tested this plugin configuration on eclipse on my side and it was working so I guess there is no reason eclipse would be involved in the issue

Comment: Ok, I'm under eclipse luna with m2e 1.5.1 .
As said above I dont specify any goal, I just drag and drop my webapp on my server, I understood that this was running `mvn clean package` behind, but I may be wrong...

Comment: When you to the drag and drop from eclipse to deploy on your project into your server, is it the generated war which is deployed or a folder ? This makes a very big difference because when generating the war, the `maven-war-plugin` is performing the exclusions when creating the war so it means that the temp folder used contains **all** the resources (including the excludes).

Comment: As suggested in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403197/m2e-default-lifecycle-when-adding-webapp-to-tomcat-server), it might a better solution to use some plugin to deploy the war to the server to ensure that it's the generated war which is deployed. If you don't want to use the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` there is the `cargo-maven2-plugin` which is more generic.

Comment: Ok, when you say "use some plugin to deploy" you mean another plugin than the default `maven-war-plugin` I assume?
I'll try it when I'll have time, and see if the exclude work better with another plugin...

Comment: Yep, with `tomcat7-maven-plugin` or `cargo-maven2-plugin` for example. There is an easy way to know if the war is correctly generated : open the target folder with your file explorer (Windows Explorer for example), open the generated war with an archiver application like 7Zip or WinZip (the `war` is just a `zip` renammed) and check if your excluded files are in it or not. In the temp folder which is at the side of your generated war in the target folder will contain the excluded files for sure because the exclusion is generated at the war file creation.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding the same issue within Intellij IDEA which is using Maven 3.
The war file it generates contains the directory I am excluding.
**UPD**
Solution is to use syntax as below to eliminate the myFolder directory

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
      <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/myFolder/**</exclude>
         </excludes>
    </resource>

</webResources>
```